# Contact Form 7 Required Checkbox Group Validation Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am using a Contact Form 7 form in Wordpress. I have a group of checkboxes, of which I would like to make sure at least one is checked before the form is submitted. Should be simple enough... With the built in validation, because I am not using the CF7 short code, but html input markup, even if the fields are set to required, the form submits. I cannot use the short code because my input field names contain [] brackets. So, I installed Jquery validation plugin for CF7, which works fine to disallow the form to be submitted if none of the boxes are checked, but if you check, say, the first 3 boxes, only the values of the second and third boxes are sent through the form. I have looked around at several custom validation code snippets which look like they would work and I paste them into the same area as I have other similar snippets doing other things and they don't make a difference because the built in CF7 validation doesn't stop the form from submitting when the required fields of my html input fields aren't checked. Any suggestions? I am not a coder (doing my best though) so please feel free to answer like I am a child lol. Here is my html:

```
<p>
<label>Which Are You Most Interested In?</label>
</br>
<label for="cb1">
    <input id="cb1" name="mc4wp-INTERESTS[de9f89w3vq][]" 
type="checkbox" value="bf2fd8233f" required> <span>Interest 1</span>
</label>
</br>
<label for="cb2">
    <input id="cb2" name="mc4wp-INTERESTS[de9f89w3vq][]" 
type="checkbox" value="c1b1b74e7c" required> <span>Interest 2</span>
</label>
</br>
<label for="cb3">
    <input id="cb3" name="mc4wp-INTERESTS[de9f89w3vq][]" 
type="checkbox" value="a4c5eb6f36" required> <span>Interest 3</span>
</label>
</br>
<label for="cb4">
    <input id="cb4" name="mc4wp-INTERESTS[de9f89w3vq][]" 
type="checkbox" value="587de639d6" required> <span>Interest 4</span>
</label>
</p>
```

--

I figured the best way for me to go about this is to just disable the submit button until the group of checkboxes has had at least one value checked (and another set of radio buttons having had one checked) and found this code:

```
(function($) {

function buttonState(){
    $("input").each(function(){
        $('#send-info').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        if($(this).val() == "" ) return false;
        $('#send-info').attr('disabled', '');
   }) 
}

$(function(){
$('#send-info').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$('input').change(buttonState);
})
})(jQuery);
```

... Which works really nicely to disable the submit button, however it seems like since I have hidden fields it does not re-enable the submit button. Also not sure if it cares about required fields only. Wondering how to modify it so that it only cares about required fields and ignores hidden fields. I tried several other snippet solutions and for some reason they were not disabling the submit button. I have the script installed at the bottom of the page via Scripts and Styles Wordpress plugin.